# Magento product specific shipping tax

Tags: magento2.2

I checked in admin and I was wondering if there is any way to achieve this:

For example:

- Product A and B has price 100
- Product A has tax 10% and B without tax
- And shipping price according to their weight should be 10 for both products
- Cart total should be **231** = 100(Product A price) + 110(Product B price) + 11 (Shipping price for product A with TAX) + 10 (Shipping price for product B without TAX)

I hope this calculation makes more sense.

**Main logic I want to implement is Shipping tax should apply to A because A it self has tax and shipping tax should not apply to B because B is tax-free product**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set "Tax Class for Shipping = Taxable Goods" or any custom the tax class you are using with products. from admin configurations Store > Configuration > Sales > Tax Classes 
[image]

Comment: This will add shipping tax for all Products. But i want to add shipping tax to some of the products only not for all

Comment: it will only apply shipping tax to those products how have tax class = taxable goods

Comment: thanks for getting back but it does not solve the problem. I have updated the question?
If you think your solution will still work give me some more details please